# Android: Search installed package with Intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I don't know if this questing ever asked before, tried to search and found nothing.

Is that possible to search and display installed package by checking it's manifest if contains specific intent filter?

Ex: I want to display installed package that contains custom Intent Filter on it's manifest

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.example.one" />
</intent-filter>
```

As a sample, then if application is exist, I want to make a text "Application Exist" on a textview

```
if (...//checking if application exist or not) {
      textview.setText("Application Exist");
}
else {
...
}
```

Comment: so you just want to check if an application exist on the phone?

Comment: I want to check if there is installed application that contains specific intent filter (like above) inside it's manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`queryIntentActivities()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

So you create an intent with the correct filter matching discriminators on it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my_awesome.package.hasa.custom.ACTION!");
intent.addCategory("typingisfunfunfun");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("data://foo/bar"));
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
if(resolveInfo.isEmpty()) {
  Log.i("NoneResolved", "No Activities");
} else {
  Log.i("Resolved!", "There are activities" + resolveInfos);
}
```

Comment: Still confused how to use that, no sample code. It will be helpful if you or someone can provide a sample, please ...

Comment: I'm sorry for too much asking, but I'm still confused how to use that. I have edited my question, could you please give another sample, please ...

Comment: I believe the last sample did basically the same thing. This should be enough to do as you said, ask and have pseudocoded